# Grayscale image taking more space on disk than RGB when exported using MATLAB's 'imwrite' command

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The size of the scaled grayscale image of size 256x256 is shown to be greater (65 kB) when saved using `imwrite()` than the original RGB image, which is of size 23 kB.

The extension of the file used is .bmp

```
img = imread('\path\input_image.bmp');

img=rgb2gray(img);

img=imresize(img,[256,256]);

imwrite(img, '\path\op_img.bmp', 'bmp');
```

Expected output: grayscale image occupies less space on the disc.

Actual output: grayscale image occupies more space than the same RGB image on the disc.

Comment: What's the size of `img` before you resize it?

Comment: if it's the same image, why do you have to resize the output to 256x256 pixels? what is the input image's dimensions?

Comment: Your rgb image is compressed and/or you have made the grayscale version larger (see `imresize`).

Comment: Please upload your original BMP image. It is likely an image with lots of uniform areas, which the RLE compression in BMP files can compress well. The file you write is not compressed, given it’s size.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab imwrite saves the .bmp image uncompressed.

If you save a 8bit grayscale image with 256x256 pixels as .bmp you'll end up with a file size of 256x256/1024kB = 64kB.

So there are two possible reasons for your input image to be smaller in size.

1. you increased the pixel count with the imresize operation

   more pixels -> more data -> more memory
2. the input image was compressed

or any combination of both.